# How to write and transform Adobe blur property value in CSS?

Tags: css, adobe-xd

How to convert Adobe blur properties to CSS?
How to explain in CSS this Adobe blur `backdrop:filter()`?

> AdobeXd amount = 46 to css = px?

> AdobeXd Brightness = -16 to css = ?

> AdobeXd Opacity = 71% to css = ?

[image]

Comment: `filter:blur(5px)` , `opacity:0.5;` , `filter:brightness(0.5);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in css you can use filters like `filter: blur(8px);` to add blur to your image `filter: brightness()` to control brightness and `filter: opacity()` for opacity.

here is an example:

```css
img {
  filter: blur(10px) brightness(1.75) opacity(80%);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/368px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png">
```

Comment: I attached a Screenshot of this property how to write it in detail.

Comment: @StatusOcean i don't understand, do you have your code? i can help you change

Comment: ok but I need this adobe property in CSS. Thank you.

Comment: @StatusOcean yes you can change the the css code i gave you as per the property you showed

Comment: if my answer helped please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  :)

Comment: AdobeXd  Background blur :

AdobeXd amount = 46 to css = px?

AdobeXd  Brightness = -16 to css = ?

AdobeXd Opacity = 71% to css = ?

Comment: @StatusOcean if you want to translate the values what i suggest is to publish your AdobeXd for web and use inspector to see the values, see https://www.guidingtech.com/export-adobe-xd-html/

Comment: but I have not used the premium account for adobe xd is not provide a live link to show a preview in the browser. I, not useable inspector option.

Comment: @StatusOcean sorry that is as far as i can help, good luck